# Is it possible for VBA to recognize a row with Formulas and autofill just those rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible, and if so, how to write up VBA code to Autofill to lrow in an excel spreadsheet all Formulas (and only formulas) in row 2. I was thinking maybe an IF then statement but I'm not sure how that would look. I'm not sure how to identify only Formulas in Row two then have them autofill to the last row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by "AutoFill", do you mean the tool within Excel?  Note that there is an [`IsFormula()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isformula).

Comment: Well I was thinking of defining a formula as string and then using that with a range of special cells but so far that hasn't been successful. By Autofill I mean to run the formula to the last row of data on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use specialcells to find cells containing formulas

```
Dim lrow As Long, a As Range
lrow = 7
For Each a In Range("2:2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Areas
    a.Resize(lrow - 1, a.columns.count).FillDown
Next a
```

Comment: This returns a "List separator or )" expected error can't see where either would apply though since all open ( are closed.

Comment: This is a good start! it def gives me something to work with as well.  It works for the first column but doesn't seem to be hitting the others. There are formulas from AK to AP and AR to AW and it's running for AK and AR but not the others.